# Blueimp file upload error message for invalid files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, blueimp

I've limited blueimp file upload plugin to certain file types/sizes in the upload.php handler.

The plugin is working fine for the correct file types (json) within the size limits but for other file types, it doesn't upload (as expected) but it isn't throwing any error message.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if(file.error != null){
                    $('#consola').text(file.error);
                };
                myfunction();
            });
        }
    });
```

I've also tried:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if(file.error){
                    $('#consola').text(file.error);
                };
                myfunction();
            });
        },
    });
```

Why is the error message not displayed?

Comment: Why not `console.log(data.result);` and see what it gives you?

Comment: It gives: ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Where did you place the logging statement? It has to be inside of the `done: function (e, data) {` block.

Comment: Try logging the argument e

Comment: @cillosis it returns Object {files: Array[1]}

Comment: console(e) returns: b.Event {type: "fileuploaddone", timeStamp: 1382456086313, jQuery1910646068372298032: true, target: input#fileupload.button-default, isTrigger: true…}

Comment: I can see the response from the server is something like: {"files":[{"name": ... , "error":"File not allowed"}]} How do I get the error message? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if(file.error !=null){
                    $('#consola').text(file.error);
                    animarTexto();
                } else {
                    myFunction();   
                }
            });
        }
    });
```